# TYPO3 BackEnd settings - “Select & upload files” and “Add media by URL”

Tags: typo3, settings, backend

Is it possible with TypoScript configuration or via TCA to disable file uploads and keep the posibility to add media files by url (see screenshot)?

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 1):

File uploads are only possible when the user has access to the folder `user_upload`. If you restrict the access for the user one can't see the "Select & upload files" any more.

Comment: ...but the "add media by url" button is still available? 

Because using `TCEFORM.tt_content.media.config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 0` disable both buttons ("upload file" and "add media by url")

Answer (score 0):

This feature is being discussed here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84250
You can see the patch here: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60752

Via composer patches you can use this feature today (not merged yet in master).
I'm on 9.5.8 and it works great.